# Olympus E-M10 Mark II - zoom in live view with manual lens

Tags: olympus, live-view

So I’ve got a manual lens for my Olympus E-M10 Mark II, and while I could turn on focus peaking, sometimes I want to zoom in a bit before I shoot.

For the AF lens with the electrical contacts, it can detect the focus ring and zoom.

Is there a function in the camera that I missed? I did go through the manual before but didn’t recall seeing something like a manual zoom...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have previous version of this camera (Olympus E-M10), but I think there is no big difference in LiveView  mode and using non-native lenses between E-M10 and E-M10 Mark II .

You have two ways:

1. Use the right adapter
2. Use the surrogate zoom in video mode

**1st way**

You connect non-native lenses to your camera body using some adapter. To zoom picture and have a "zebra"-assistant in LiveView with manual lenses you have to use adapter **with chip** (also known as dandelion-chip) on it. This chip has a special function which deceives the camera, telling to it: "the attached lense is native but in manual mode". I have two such adapters (for SONY/Minolta and Canon lenses, others still have no chips) with that function, so, I think you can find similar (or buy the chip only, then you have to stick it correctly).

Here is my old adapter for SONY/Minolta lenses -> m4/3 camera:

[image]

Here is my new adapter for SONY/Minolta lenses -> m4/3 camera with chip:

[image]

[image: here that chip marked by red color]

**2nd way**

Without that chip you can use a surrogate approach:

1. Set the (P), (S) or (M) mode for video shooting in Options.
2. Switch to the video shoooting mode.
3. Display the movie teleconvertor frame (usually the Fn2 button), then turn on it (the Fn2 button again).
4. Now you have the central area zoomed but without "zebra"-assistant. Catch your object in focus, then shoot it! (yes, in video mode!). But this surrogate focus sometimes can help you!

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Menu -> Custom menu (Gear) -> Button/Dial -> Button Function, then assign one of the buttons to 'Magnify'. You'll still have to push this button to go into zoom mode, but that's easier than video mode teleconvertor trick